# AVPlayerLayer is not visible is view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have `AVPlayerLayer` in a `UIView` and this is how i add it to the `UIView`:

```
[[self.playerView layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
```

Also i have `UITabBarController` with 5 `UIViewController`.The `AVPlayerLayer` is in the 5 tab.

And now in iOS 7 when i go to background mode and return to the app the video is still playing but not show in the UIView.

I tried to check if it's still in the UIView with :

```
NSArray *arr = [self.playerView layer].sublayers;
```

I tried to remove and add it again but it still not there :

```
[avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
[[self.playerView layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
```

and `AVPlayerLayer` is still there.

Any idea how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

set the AVPlayer in the AVPlayerLayer only when it is in a visible view.
You probably have another view controller with a view on top of it.